# How i do countdown from txt file in label?

Tags: vb.net

my program create a file in desktop called dateTime.txt and this contains the hours,minutes and seconds when the app is executed.

i want do countdown but i dont know how read the text file in VB.
For example: dateTime.Text = 12:03:05
i want add 5 hours.  dateTime2.Text = 17:03:05
and later i want add a timer for get in my label an countdown.

sorry for my english

this is my code:

```
        Dim timeExecPath As String = "C:\\Users\\ignac\\Desktop\\dateTime.txt"
        If (File.Exists(timeExecPath)) Then
            Dim objReader As New StreamReader(timeExecPath)
            Label1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd()

        Else
            Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(timeExecPath)
            Dim info As Byte() = New UTF8Encoding(True).GetBytes(Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length)
            fs.Close()

        End If
```

Comment: This looks like vb.net, not vb6, so remove the unneeded tag and update the title.

Comment: If I'm looking at this correctly, in VB.NET, you want to read the time from a TXT file and add to it? If I am getting warm here, `Convert.ToDateTime(Label1.Text)` might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry,  im newbie here... im trying to get TimeNow and TimeElapsed. and get countdown in label...